# Java Observer and Observable when to remove

Tags: java

I want to implement the observer in my code

I have a pattern as follows

```
public class MyObservable extends Observable {

    public void setSomething(Object something) {
        this.something = something;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(something);
    }
}
```

at some point, I add an observer to this class and all works well.

now comes the problem.
When my observer is no longer used.
When do I remove the observer?
do I need to?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

Say you are searching for a job, you will register online for job through some portal and will register to the job alerts on your email and then act as an Observer. This means you added yourself as an Observer and observing all the job notifications in your mail for yourself and then based on notification applying/rejecting some notification of the job.

Now lets say one lucky day you get the job, you will de-register from the portal that means you are removing yourself as an observer and you would no longer get notifications.

Comment: Well I understood that, Thank you. But this is not what I meant in my question.

I have a piece of code that contains some model objects that are observing some observables. When I leave the screen that displays these objects, I expect these observers to die,because they should be garbage collected. In this case, do I need to unregister the observers ? or they just leak ? if so which java method (in lifecycle of a normal object) allows me to do this ? (and no i don't mean deleteObserver, i mean which method do i call deleteObserver from) do I even need to call this method?

Comment: Just have something like `try { show page} finally { deleteObserver}`

Comment: where ? (this text is no needed and only written to make the comment longer)

Comment: Yes you should call the method. Where depends on your app. Find a method that is triggered when you leave the screen. For example: OnPause for android, windowclosing event for swing. If you are using a button to close the screen its onclick event. In this method have your observers remove themselves.